# Which pathways/mechanisms could control some Synaptic clefts in series by Somatic Nervous System?

Tags: synapses, cognition

I listened a talk where the speaker said that this can probably be possible by Weak Quantum Cognition Theory.

I see that there is no evidence at the moment, only theory.
I see no pathways by which this could happen directly such that the **quantum entanglement** and **quantum superposition** could happen.
They should happen in a series, but I see no system holding the signal going on.

I think this is a only a hypothesis, without any supportive  evidence.

Probably, some type of synaptic cleft can be controlled, but still I see no evidence or no pathway or pathways.

I do not understand which pathway/pathways this could happen.
What is the target mechanism? Presynaptic membrane or postsynaptic neuron?

**Which are possible pathways that could control the secretion of synaptic cleft?**